# Prefilling the student information in the HTML page (in powerschool)

Tags: jquery, html, web

Actually I have created a HTML page which is to be incorporated to the powerschool website. This HTML page will be displayed when user selects the student from the list.
I am confused how to have the controls on that HTML page filled with the student information when user selects the student. Should I query the database to fetch all the information ?

Can anyone help?

Thank you,
Aman

Comment: If you are storing the data about the students in a database, then I would wager you would need to query your database. Unless you load all the student data on the page load and store it in Session or client side Storage for use on drop down change.

Answer (score 0):

Aman,

PowerSchool uses a reference number in the link URL to tell it which student to display in the page.

Check out [this forum thread](https://support.powerschool.com/thread/3214), and note posts #2 and 14.

You don't actually query the database.  (See post #12 in the above thread.)  You just have the student fields in the page and the reference number in the URL.

Note that you'll need a PowerSource account to access that information.